# Where can i find jslint config file in Aptana Studio

Tags: aptana, jslint, jslint4java

I am trying to replace jslint config file. I want to add my own pre-defined config file instead of jslint config file. Could anyone explain, where can i find jslint config file in Aptana Studio 3 directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using JSHint but I think the config is alike. You cannot use a config file in Aptana unlike in WebStorm (at least I do not know how). You can only configure JSLint in the IDE via the preference menu. There you can paste the content of your config file in the configuration menu.

[image: JSHint]